# How to tell when 知らない is "I don't care"?

Tags: negation

> もし世の中君のような顔ばかりだったら それに慣れてしまって何とも思わなくなるのかな?

If everyone looked like you people would get used and it wouldn't be effective  (your look)

> 知りません! そんなことは

To which the character answers

Is it possible that 知りません here is "I don't care about it"? Rather than "I don't know"? How does one tell?

Comment: In some cases yes, but it looks like the quote literally means *I don't know!*.

Answer (score 2):

It helps to think of 知らない as the meaning of "I don't know" in **both** contexts.

Rather than English "I don't care", it's more like saying "I don't know so stop bothering me about it", or "I have nothing to do with this" kind of connotation, meant to brush someone off.

You're right this example is confusing because both would make sense. From only this I can't say for sure either. I'd say if you think their intention was to brush the first character off it for sure means "I don't care", but if anything other than that I'd take it as literally not knowing.

Hope this helps :)